# Create a new image from existing container but data is not copied?

Tags: python, image, docker, visual-studio-code

I have created a new image from the existing container but the problem is
Container1: data folder
New Container: No data folder.
I am attaching the screenshots as well. Can somebody tell me what should I do I don't have access to the docker hub due to some reasons?[image without data new container created from existing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzQYm.jpg)

[image with data from which new container created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz74G.jpg)

I have used the commit command and then create a container from the image.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing the error messages and the actual code that causes the problem; can you edit the question to include these details in the question (not behind links) and as plain text (not as images)?  I can tell you that running `docker commit` is almost never a best practice; it's far better to write the steps to build an image into a Dockerfile, check that file into source control, and use `docker build` to create (or recreate!) an image.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.